# Reversible card in HTML5 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I would like you to help me to simplify my code or to build a shorter javascript code for the application that I have created to get into the world of programming. (I really feel quite rookie yet). It consists on some cards that change its content (text) when the user clicks on these.

Sorry if the code is quite bad. I'm starting to learn on my own.
Many many thanks for the answers.

The code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>



body{background-color:lightblue;
}
    #demo, #demo2{
        padding:20px 3px;
        display:inline;
        margin-top:2000px;
        border-radius:20px;

    }

    #demo:focus, #demo2:focus{
        outline:0px;
    }

    section{
        margin:auto;
        padding-top:50px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        width:500px;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>

<section>

<div id="demo" tabindex="-1" onblur="myfirstblurfunction()">Card1</div>
<div id="demo2" tabindex="-1" onblur="mysecondblurfunction()">Card2</div>
<script>





//function



var timesClicked1= 0;

document.getElementById("demo").onclick=function() {myFunction1()};

function myFunction1(){
timesClicked1++;



//If the user clicks once
if(timesClicked1==1){
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="orange";
}


//If the user clicks odd times but not the first

else if(timesClicked1%2!==0 && timesClicked1!==1){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Card1";
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="orange";
document.getElementById("demo").style.border="none";


}


//If the user clicks even times
else{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="King";
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
document.getElementById("demo").style.border="solid";

}

}



//When the user clicks outside the element, returns to the initial state
function myfirstblurfunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Card1";
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
document.getElementById("demo").style.border="none";


return timesClicked1=0;

}




//function 2 (It's the same, but with -Card2-Queen-)


var timesClicked2 = 0;

document.getElementById("demo2").onclick=function() {myFunction2()};

function myFunction2(){
timesClicked2++;

if(timesClicked2==1){
document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor="orange";
}

else if(timesClicked2 %2!==0 && timesClicked2!==1){
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="Card2";
document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor="orange";

}
else{
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="queen";
document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor="lightblue";

document.getElementById("demo2").style.border="solid";
}

}

function mysecondblurfunction(){
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML="Card2";
document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
document.getElementById("demo2").style.border="none";

return timesClicked2=0;

}
</script>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be a better question for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)